# Translation of “crapware”

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

*[Crapware](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/57729/crapware)* is some software that has little value. The term often refers to the numerous trial applications that are pre-installed on a new computer. How would you say *crapware* in French?

Answer (score 7):

Il me semble que le plus adapté serait sans doute le **pourriciel** déjà proposé, bien que je ne pense pas qu'il y ait une traduction officielle. Néanmoins, **pourriciel** traduit bien l'idée du logiciel non désiré qui en plus pourri la vie de l'utilisateur, rendant son PC plus lent, ou utilisant de l'espace disque.

**Merdiciel** pourrait convenir, mais est déjà plus argotique. Cela dépend un peu de l'état d'esprit de l'utilisateur. Dans tous les cas, **pourriciel** pourrait être utilisé à l'écrit, alors que **merdiciel** est d'un emploi plus délicat autrement qu'à l'oral.

Answer (score 4):

J'ai déjà entendu *merdiciel*, mais je n'ai pas l'impression que c'est commun.

Comment: Quand on me dit merdiciel je dis *shitware*, mais je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de différence entre *shitware* et *crapware*, tout au plus de niveau de langue.

Answer (score 3):

J'ai pensé à « pourriciel » comme alternative à « merdiciel » pour garder la différence de niveau de langue entre  et *crapware* et *shitware* (un peu plus vulgaire).

Cependant l'utilisation de *pourriciel* me semble assez diverse, je crois que le mot est parfois utilisé dans le sens de logiciel malveillant.

J'ai quand même trouvé  sur ce [forum « informatique](http://forum.telecharger.01net.com/forum/high-tech/LOISIRS/Debats/pourriciels-sujet_5551_1.htm) » le mot utilisé avec le sens de *crapware*. Donc je le soumets à réflexion.

Comment: Since the language is allowed to evolve in that field and *pourriciel* may have an unwanted connotation of why not propose a neologism, using the same portmanteau rules:**bidoniciel**?

Answer (score 3):

Le lien de la question fait allusion à *logiciel pré-installé*.

*[Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=crapware)* donne une seule réponse :

- *logiciel promotionnel* qui est une autre façon de définir ces logiciels *crappy* du point de vue mercantile.

D'autre possibilités dérivées de *crap* ou de *shit*

- *Logiciel bidon* du point de vue de l'utilisateur final qui n'a pas entre les mains le logiciel annoncé, mais quelque chose de minable.
- *Logiciel merdique* : soit il ne fonctionne pas du tout, soit il est d'une ergonomie insupportable ou encore il est complètement bogué.

Answer (score 1):

Jamais entendu d'équivalent en français, 
Tocquiciel?

Answer (score 1):

Since the language is still allowed to evolve in that field and *pourriciel* may have an unwanted connotation of hurting the user, why not propose a neologism?

Some avenues of investigation:

1. Using the same portmanteau rules: *bidoniciel*
2. Using another (humourous and not warranted yet by grammarians) [construction by translating the -ware sound with a similar -oir word in French, with similar meaning](http://jargonf.org/wiki/ware): *foutouère*. The principle of borrowing sounds from English is already admitted (bifteck, cédérom).
3. Or keep it simple and call it *foutoir* (knowing that Québecois and some regional French accents might pronounce it anyway with a sound not too far from -ware, as used to be the traditional way).